# React updating without use of setState

Tags: reactjs

I have read a few answers regarding my question but I am still not sure how to fix this issue.  I have a tree object that is moderately nested.  When updating the values in the tree I am well aware of the rules not to update the state directly, so I create a shallow copy of the tree, make the modifications and update the state for the tree to be properly displayed.  I noticed something odd; however.  When I update the shallow copy of the tree, the state gets updated.....I am not sure how or why, but I am sure it's a concept I am not understanding.  Would love some help getting around this if it IS an issue:

```
export const FldDataTree = (props) => {          
    const [treeData, setTreeData] = useState({data:[]})  

    const findNode = (node,id) => {               
        let result;         
        for(let i=0;i<node.length;i++){                        
            if(node[i].recordid == id) return(node[i]);            
            if(node[i].children){
                result=findNode(node[i].children,id);
            }        
            return result;
         }
     }

     const HandleFormCallback = (resp) => {                
         if(resp.action=="save"){            
             if(controls.editid){       
                 let ns = treeData.data;                 
                  let node = findNode(ns,controls.editid)                                 
                  if(node){
                      node.foldername = resp.data.foldername
                      console.log(treeData.data)     //<=============treeData.data was updated....why?
                  }
              }
          }
      }
```

Comment: Its because you're setting `ns` equal to `treeData.data`. When you're doing this you're not assigning to ns tree data value, you're referencing to it, if you want to make a real copy then use spread operator to create a new object... something like `let ns = [...treeData.data]`. This will do the work.

Comment: Thank you for your response, Ezequiel.  I've changed the code to everything I can think of: `ns=[{...treeData.data}]` or `ns=[...treeData.data]` or `ns={...treeData}` and it still will not return the value.  Id I pass the actual treeData.data (which I am not supposed to do) then the correct value comes back.

Comment: That's weird, i've worked with tree structures and the spread operator works... Can you add an example of what your teeData.data looks like?... I saw that in your if statements you use '==' instead of '===', i recommend you to change it! Also change `return(node[i])` to `return node[i]`

Comment: It is weird, but I was able to solve the problem  using `deepClone`.  But I am confused because I thought the way you suggested doing it was a deep copy and not shallow.  So, I'm not really sure, but the problem was solved by using a third party library.  Thanks for yur help, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, the shallow copy won't work, as it's a tree structure the nested objects won't get cloned.

To do a deep copy you can use `let ns = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(treeData.data))` or any third party library for deep copy.

Comment: Thanks Sandipan.  I used `deepClone` to solve the problem. I appreciate the answer.